# How do I encrypt specific variables/columns in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataset

There are certain variables in my data frame which need to be encrypted because it contains sensitive data.How do I go about encrypting these columns/variables?

Comment: Do you really want these data *encrypted* (so that nobody can use them for any purpose without decrypting them) or just *anonymized* so that they can be used for analysis without revealing details about individuals?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PKI/index.html) in R which can do encryption.

An example:

```
require(PKI)
key <- PKI.genRSAkey(2048)
x <- charToRaw("Hello, world!")
e <- PKI.encrypt(x, key)
y <- PKI.decrypt(e, key)
stopifnot(identical(x, y))
print(rawToChar(y))
```

which produces an encrypted message of "Hello World" which would be displayed as:

```
e
[1] 36 83 d3 70 0a 67 b5 05 a6 40 1e 37 28 b9 4e 28 f1 31 92 14 2c 35 c8 8a 61 93 1e 04 62 01 da 3b 2b a0 75 1c 10 58 26
 [40] e4 77 da 7a 47 3f 4e 44 29 8e 97 6f 62 b1 98 44 ba 18 ef 57 1e 9e 9c 27 a8 6e 9c 7b c7 8b c0 c3 a3 00 e2 67 98 8b 6e
 [79] 1a 93 c6 d6 ed 4b 54 e5 7a 07 d7 06 ef a6 bb 36 6a 7f 57 06 b9 15 03 f6 51 3f 07 48 cb f4 2d 25 15 be 42 de f4 8a 06
[118] 72 89 b1 e3 04 d3 ec 80 99 f0 66 0f 84 e1 b5 af 23 24 a1 36 8e 62 65 ae 19 fb 77 d1 36 06 ae 71 95 ee 57 aa 68 5a 6b
[157] 4e 28 ba a2 0d 17 78 11 6c 7f 1b b3 ce 31 65 a9 d3 71 89 76 f9 19 a0 7a bf 02 dd c9 1f cb 9c 39 25 d4 48 a2 23 83 26
[196] b4 a9 b1 40 f5 1d 46 21 35 12 52 73 09 9b f3 52 e1 9e 0d 2a 9b ff 70 81 41 24 49 ed 58 b2 61 dc 3e c9 b3 b2 b1 37 e0
[235] 48 76 18 bf b0 e5 c2 d9 2b 92 2f 6b 49 dd e0 93 b7 10 f8 ba d2 8a
```

So, similarly, the entire data-frame or the column/row of choice can be encrypted.

This is [RSA](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)) encryption. In addition, there is the [digest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/digest.pdf) package, which helps you create cryptogenic hash objects (recommended); which has the **[“electronic codebook” (ECB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29)**, **[“cipher-block chaining” (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29)** and [**“counter” (CTR)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) modes.

Comment: Could you clarify what purpose this might serve? In such a form, these data are useless for statistical analysis, so why not (much more simply) delete them?

Comment: @whuber It ensures that encrypted data is stored in the db, and used by the analyst at convenience.

So, now the data is safe in the db, until only the analyst knows how to decrypt it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  I can appreciate how some people might find it convenient to keep everything in the `R` environment.

Comment: @whuber In fact, all of this can be in the `R` environment completely, including the storage and retrieval of data from db's.

Encryption comes handy while dealing with sensitive data or in production.

Comment: A specific use-case: You want to key on that data but and you know that the output will be shared in insecure ways (think PII on a cloud server). Encrypting usernames (for example) across files, using the same encryption key, would allow you to key on the encrypted usernames and share the files with others on, say, github, without having to worry about breaching your corporate data policy.